# Text animation glitch on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create an animation, which moves text up and shows some content when hovered over a card. When hovered over the card, the animation works as expected but when the cursor is placed on top of the text, there's this weird glitch and the text keeps moving up and down.

I've put this up on : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qGwpaG

My code

HTML

```
 <section class="section" id="black">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="display-4 d-flex justify-content-center spacing text-center light bold mt-3" id="case-head"> Make something you love.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row no-gutters">


      <div class="col-lg-4">
          <a href="blog.html" class="hover">

            <div class="image">
              <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3766/12953056854_b8cdf14f21.jpg" class="">
            </div>
          <p class="img-text color bold">Sample - 1</p>
          <p class="img-description light">Lorem Ipsum  </p>
          <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right img-description arrow"></i> 
           </a>
        </div>
  </section>
```

CSS

```
    .img-text {
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 16px;
    font-size: 30px;

  }

  .img-description{


    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 35px;
    left: 16px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;

  }

  .image {
    position:relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
.image img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.image:after {
    content:'\A';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.image:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}
.color
{
  color: white!important;
}
```

JS

```
$('.img-description').hide();

$(".hover").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find(".img-text").animate({ bottom: 100 },100);
    $(this).find('.img-description').show();
})

$(".hover").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find(".img-text").animate({ bottom: 8 });
    $(this).find('.img-description').hide();
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that only the parent element is triggering the events. When using mouseover/mouseout, any child element will also trigger these events, which you don't want.

To fix this, you can either use mouseenter/mouseleave or, even better, use the `hover` [shorthand](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$(".hover").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find(".img-text").animate({ bottom: 100 }, 100);
    $(this).find(".img-description").show();
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find(".img-text").animate({ bottom: 8 });
    $(this).find(".img-description").hide();
  }
);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYgxWv

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much !